# Installing the segment-iOS analytics-iOS in xcode manually

Tags: ios, xcode, segment-io

I am trying to add analytics-iOS manually by directly adding the Analytics folder to the project making it as a group, after adding when I try to build the project I get error as "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

```
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKProductsRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SEGStoreKitTracker.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKPaymentQueue", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SEGStoreKitTracker.o "
```

and other 6 errors

Comment: `SEGStoreKitTracker` is not added to your target.
Click on `analytics-iOS` > Go to File Inspector (First Right Tab) > Add to your target (Target Membership).

Comment: This file is added to the target. Even if i try installing using pods i get same error but instead of SEGStoreKitTracker.o it says AppDelegate.o

Comment: Are you opening `.xcodeproj` or `.workspace`?

Comment: Well seems like there were some settings which i was missing while doing through pods, So now its running through pods install but still same problem with adding manually. I was opening .workspace

Comment: I was able to solve this. There was a dependency on StoreKit framework which i had to add in Link Binaries with Libraries in Build Phase.

Comment: Great! Well done, keep it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this. There was a dependency on StoreKit framework which i had to add in Link Binaries with Libraries in Build Phase.